# php string operation

Tags: php

I have stucked into a typical php string program.
I have a data string like

```
$str="{heading}
{youtube}4vfOPm6wfyI{/youtube}
{/heading}
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium</p>";
```

now i want the 4vfOPm6wfyI , the id of the link.
How it will be done?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you want to parse a [Smarty Template](http://www.smarty.net/). Why not just use the official engine instead of hacking a regular expression together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **explode** to find the key. This will extract the key for you:

```
$arr = explode("{youtube}", $str);
$arr = explode("{/youtube}", $arr[1]);
$key = $arr[0];
print $key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a regular expression search/replace of `\{youtube\}(.*?)\{\/youtube\}` with the proper embed line:

```
<object width="640" height="385">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1"></param>
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    width="640" 
    height="385"></embed>
</object>
```

EDIT: If you just want to capture what's in between the {youtube} and {/youtube}, do something like this:

```
if (ereg ("\{youtube\}(.*?)\{\/youtube\}", $str, $regs)) {
  print "<p>The youtube link is: http://www.youtube.com/v/$regs[1]</p>";
}
```

Comment: -1: While the regular expression would work, using the actual parser engine intended to be used for the markup in the original question would be more appropiate in this case **IMHO**.